# How can I optimize my three.js program? Only one mesh causes significant lag

Tags: optimization, memory, three.js

I'm working on drawing shapes in three.js and I have a small working version of what I'm trying to accomplish:

https://jsfiddle.net/tclcp/oawcxk4r/1/

The important bit of code is really at the end: lines 88-139.

To use it, make two separate clicks in the canvas. that will enter "draw mode" where a pink triangle displays. Any more clicks will apply the triangle and repeat.

to make it lag, I like to start with a vertical line and start spiraling. after about 30 triangles, my computer is really struggling

The preview triangle is not the issue; this happens even without it running.

The weird part is i dont see much being hogged in Task Manager or in Dev Tools..

I definitely am making a lot of `Float32Array`s, should I be explicitly deleting them when I'm done?

Am I making too many `new Vector3`s? I've seen people talk about reusing whatever possible. I can definitely reuse some of mine..but haven't tried

here's a snippet without going to jsfiddle

```
    let firstClickPoint, lastClickPoint;
    const cmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });

    let clickGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    let clickedArray = new Float32Array();
    let clickMesh = new THREE.Mesh();

    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var pointToAdd = new THREE.Vector3();
        getMouseCoords(e.clientX, e.clientY, camera, pointToAdd)

        if (firstClickPoint === undefined) {
            firstClickPoint = pointToAdd;
        }
        else if (lastClickPoint === undefined) {
            lastClickPoint = pointToAdd;
        }
        else {

            clickedArray = new Float32Array([
                ...clickedArray,
                firstClickPoint.x, firstClickPoint.y, firstClickPoint.z,
                lastClickPoint.x, lastClickPoint.y, lastClickPoint.z,
                pointToAdd.x, pointToAdd.y, pointToAdd.z,
            ]);

            clickGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(clickedArray, 3));

            lastClickPoint = pointToAdd;
            clickMesh = new THREE.Mesh(clickGeometry, cmaterial);

            scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("pMesh"));
            scene.add(clickMesh);
            
        }

    });
```

Comment: It's not laggy for me on a Macbook, but I notice you're creating a `new THREE.Mesh` on every mousemove, if you can find a way to instead update the geometry of the existing mesh, that might improve performance

Comment: I was wondering the best way to get the preview to appear and reappear but forgot to put that in my question, thank you. It seemed intensive to be adding and removing it from the scene

Comment: The amount of Vector3s you create has almost zero impact on performance. I would use the Chrome inspector Javascript profiler to record you moving the mouse, and use the flamegraph display to figure out where the most time is being spent.